# Windows Server 2019 vs Windows Hyper-V Server 2019

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I have a server with Windows Server 2019 Standard (with Desktop environment).

I want to transform it in a vps server, so what is the best: my Windows Server + Hyper-V role or Windows Hyper-V Server 2019?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering it's a Standard version of Windows Server, you won't be able to deploy more than 2 VMs on it, according to Microsoft's version comparison:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/editions-comparison-19
So your first option wouldn't be quite viable to go with.

Comment: Note that that's the number of Windows guest instances you are licensed for, not the maximum number of VMs allowed.  The OP doesn't make it clear what OS the guests will be running so this might or might not be a problem.  (And Windows licensing for vps is probably an entire other kettle of worms anyway.)